# How to best "compress" a 32 character hexadecimal UUID with URL-safe characters?

Tags: url, hash, encoding, base64

I was hoping to shorten the UUIDs for database entries in order to make URL-safe and shareable as permalinks. While it's possible for us to have a separate cached table of "pointers" for these with fewer characters, I was wondering if there was a better way?

The best way I can think of off the top of my head is to `base64` encode them instead of hexadecimal encode them. That shortens them from 32 characters to around 22. But I wanted to try to get this below 14 characters if possible. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a stab at some quick math here, so please correct me if I'm wrong. A UUID is at it's most basic level a 128-bit value ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)). That means there are 2^128 possibilities.

According to [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt),

> Characters that are allowed in a URI but do not have a reserved
>   purpose are called unreserved. These include uppercase and lowercase
>   letters, decimal digits, hyphen, period, underscore, and tilde.

So among friends let's say that's about 66 unreserved ASCII characters we can use in the URL (26+26+10+4).

Solving the [equation](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/exponential-equation-calculator/2%5E%7B128%7D-66%5E%7Bx%7D%3D0) 2^128 - 66^x = 0, x is about 21.18, meaning that, like you said with your base64 idea, a minimum of 22 unreserved ASCII characters are needed to URL-encode the UUID (at this time) and fewer characters cannot be used 100% of the time.

Having said that, on the surface (visually, in browsers) it might be possible to use unicode characters to represent larger portions of hexibits (e.g. example.com/uuid/☂☎♞ʤ☯...), but the underlying URL would be much longer than a 32-hexibit UUID as allowed URL characters are limited by the RFC. However, this would be admittedly crazy and in need of some neat algorithms to encode the UUID nicely.

Comment: Right, so `base64` is going to use A-Z and 0-9 in an upper/lowercase combination, but not the period or hyphen or underscore/tilde. So, I wonder how much of a difference adding those characters would make. URLs also do support the Unicode characters like you said, but they're not easily typed.

Comment: The browser quietly decodes the Unicode when it's pasted into the address bar. It's a visual effect only. Base64 is probably the best/tightest encoding, and quite common. Note that = or == may be appended to base64 strings so they might be 24 chars long.